# Why primitive integer can not be passed as a thread parameter?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

In my swift code, I start a thread with an integer parameter. But I found the thread function got is not as same as the one passed in `Thread.init()`. If I use string to carry the parameter, the value got is the same as I passed.

This is my code:

```swift
    @objc func run_with_uint(param: UInt) {
        os_log("run_with_uint: %ld", param)
    }
    @objc func run_with_str(param: String) {
        os_log("run_with_str: %s", param)
    }
    
    @IBAction
    func onStartClick(sender: UIButton) {
        let param: UInt = 12345678
        let t1 = Thread.init(target: self, selector: #selector(run_with_uint), object: param)
        t1.start()
        let t2 = Thread.init(target: self, selector: #selector(run_with_str), object: String(param))
        t2.start()
    }
```

output is:

```
run_with_uint: -6705266956350674278
run_with_str: 12345678
```

Why?

Comment: Could it be because you are talking to Cocoa / Objective C, where a UInt is not an "object"? Try wrapping it in an NSNumber and see what happens...

Comment: I guess so. But there is no any compile error or warning.